# Is it feasible to combine aws lex with amazon comprehend with lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lex

I want to build something using aws lex, lambda and amazon comprehend. Can we combine them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is definitely possible to use Amazon's Lex, Comprehend, and Lambda together.

[Here is a great blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-aws-lambda-and-amazon-comprehend-for-sentiment-analysis/) showing how it can be done.

> "In this post, I show you how to use AWS Lambda and Amazon Comprehend for sentiment analysis to make your Amazon Lex bots in Amazon Connect more sympathetic."